# How to improve pytorch network to be more precise

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, prediction

I have a pytorch neural network which is being trained on data containing multiple financial values and some other non numeric values translated to numbers with self created logic (for example if company belongs to some sector, value = 10, if some not interesting sector, value = 1)

I have training set from approx 1300 companies where 100 are marked with 1 as interesting, rest is -1 as not interesting

I used this example as a skeleton
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2022/10/05/binary-classification-using-pytorch.aspx?Page=1

and then I tried to change number of hidden layers, set weights, use normalization
but the results of prediction with new not clasified data is really bad

my input data looks like this

```
-4.8;7.3;-4.3;-9.0;-7.8;-6.3;-8.9;9.3;-6.4;-0.6;1.0;0.0;93.11;100.0;100.0;-1
42.0;11.1;33.4;22.1;23.4;20.8;-4.4;12.6;20.4;19.3;5.0;0.0;24.34;100.0;100.0;-1
94.3;22.4;39.5;76.1;0.0;66.9;-3.0;21.0;51.7;23.4;1.0;0.0;46.1;100.0;100.0;-1
1.0;0.4;0.0;-13.4;0.0;-5.1;0.5;-14.0;-5.8;-6.0;0.0;3.0;41.2;100.0;100.0;-1
-12.6;5.2;-7.0;-16.2;-17.1;-16.0;-2.1;-0.8;-15.7;-9.2;2.0;0.0;35.3;100.0;1.0;-1
-18.0;10.1;-13.3;24.6;-21.0;-26.3;4.9;8.7;-23.9;-25.5;1.0;0.0;33.2;100.0;100.0;1
18.4;-9.0;43.5;0.2;-6.0;-5.9;-10.4;5.2;-4.9;28.7;1.0;1.0;73.11;100.0;100.0;-1
0.0;3.0;-25.2;0.0;0.0;0.0;-7.6;21.7;-26.2;-20.4;0.0;0.0;2.1;10.0;100.0;-1
7.9;7.7;-1.4;3.3;5.5;6.4;-3.4;1.6;-2.7;0.1;1.0;0.0;49.41;100.0;100.0;-1
0.0;20.5;8.9;0.0;3.4;0.0;5.0;5.5;3.8;-7.6;1.0;0.0;22.22;10.0;100.0;-1
-4.7;1.9;-15.5;-12.4;0.0;-9.7;-11.8;2.3;-12.0;-9.6;2.0;0.0;27.9;100.0;1.0;-1
-4.4;0.7;4.0;-13.5;-15.6;-4.1;-7.5;-3.9;1.6;12.7;2.0;0.0;46.1;100.0;100.0;-1
```

and this is definition of the net

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hid1 = torch.nn.Linear(15, 20) 
        self.hid2 = torch.nn.Linear(20, 10)
        self.hid3 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 5)
        self.oupt = torch.nn.Linear(5, 1)

        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hid1.weight) 
        torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.hid1.bias)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hid2.weight) 
        torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.hid2.bias)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.hid3.weight) 
        torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.hid3.bias)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.oupt.weight) 
        torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.oupt.bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        z = torch.tanh(self.hid1(x))
        z = torch.tanh(self.hid2(z))
        z = torch.tanh(self.hid3(z))
        z = torch.sigmoid(self.oupt(z)) 
        return z
```

I am new to this so any hints how to change my approach is really welcomed

Comment: What performance do you currently get, i.e. what do you mean with 'results are really bad'? There could be several explanations for a model not performing well, but generally neural networks are trained with large datasets, so using just the 1300 data points you currently have might not be sufficient to achieve the accuracy you're looking for. In addition, it might also be that the features you're currently using are not informative enough.

Comment: I mean that for example last few numbers are showing categories from my "translated dictionary" and even I know which categories are resulting 1 and which -1 in train dataset, when I run it on other companies I get 1 for companies which are definitely out of itnerested category
Maybe I am doing it wrong, but I am not able to find out how to "tell" neural network what is more important and why